# Riemannian metric on the sphere $S^2$ using a parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, parametrization

How does one go about deriving the Riemannian metric on the sphere $S^2$? I was reading Lee's book and he explains quite clearly that if we consider $S^2$ embedded in $\Bbb R^3$ we can use the inclusion $\iota : S^2 \to \Bbb R^3$ to pullback the Euclidean metric $g_E$ to get a metric $g = \iota^\ast g_E$ on $S^2$, but I could not find an explicit formulae for this.

It is later in the book noted that computations on a submanifold $M \subset \widetilde{M}$ are usually carried out most conveniently in terms of a smooth local parametrization $X : U \to \widetilde{M}$ where $X(U)$ is open in $M$. He denotes $\varphi = X^{-1}:X(U) \to U$ and states that the metric $g$ is then $$X^*g = X^*\iota^*\widetilde{g}=(\iota \circ X)^*\widetilde{g}$$ where $\widetilde{g}$ is the metric on $\widetilde{M}$.

Say I want to use this to find a metric for $S^2$. I can parametrize $S^2$ with $$X(\theta,\varphi) = (\cos\theta\sin\varphi,\sin\theta\sin\varphi,\cos\varphi)$$ where $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$ and $0\le \varphi \le \pi$.

It is not entirely clear to me now how do I find the metric given by this parametrization?

Comment: Since $(\theta,\phi)$ are coordinates on $S^2$, they define a frame of coordinate vector fields $(\partial_\theta, \partial_\phi)$. Also, observe that $\partial_\theta X(\theta,\phi), \partial_\phi X(\theta,\phi) \in \mathbb{R}^3$. The definition of the standard Riemannian metric $g$ on $S^2$ is given by \begin{align*} g(\partial_\theta,\partial_\theta) &= \partial_\theta X_\theta\cdot \partial_\theta X\\ g(\partial_\theta,\partial_\phi) &= \partial_\theta X_\theta\cdot \partial_\phi X\\  g(\partial_\phi,\partial_\phi) &= \partial_\theta X_\phi\cdot \partial_\phi X\end{align*}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have a tensor field $T$ on a manifold $M$ (let's say twice-covariant, for simplicity), and coordinates $(x^1,\ldots, x^n)$ on some open subset of $M$, the components of $T$ relative to this coordinate system are defined by $$T_{ij} = T\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} ,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right),\qquad \mbox{ for }i,j=1,\ldots,n,$$and we have $$T = \sum_{i,j=1}^n T_{ij}\,{\rm d}x^i\otimes {\rm d}x^j.$$

Here, $M = \Bbb S^2$, $T = \iota^*g_E$, and the coordinates $(\theta,\varphi)$ are given by the inverse of the parametrization $X$. By taking derivatives, we see that $$\iota_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\bigg|_{X(\theta,\varphi)}\right) = \frac{\partial X}{\partial\theta}(\theta,\varphi) = -\sin\theta\sin\varphi \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg|_{X(\theta,\varphi)} + \cos\theta\sin\varphi\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg|_{X(\theta,\varphi)}, $$and so $$(\iota^*g_E)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta},\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right) = g_E\left(\frac{\partial X}{\partial\theta},\frac{\partial X}{\partial \theta}\right) = \sin^2\varphi.$$This means that $$\iota^*g_E = \sin^2\varphi\,{\rm d}\theta \otimes {\rm d}\theta + \cdots.$$

You can compute $\iota_* (\partial/\partial \varphi) = \partial X/\partial\varphi$ and the remaining components and inner products like above.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with this thing I keep seeing often done in differential/Riemannian geometry. People seem to use the word "coordinates" for something related to the parametrization interchangeably? It would look like you are doing something similar here. @ivo-terek

Comment: "Coordinates" are defined on an open subset of the manifold, and take values in an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$. "Parametrizations" are defined on an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, and take values in an open subset of the manifold. They are inverses of each other, and carry the same amount of information. It can be hard to write parametrizations explicitly if your manifold is not already embedded in some $\Bbb R^n$, so it pays off to get used to coordinates.

Comment: So in a sense what you are doing is using $\varphi := X^{-1} : U \to \Bbb R^2$ as a chart map and calling coordinates the images of points under $\varphi$? @ivo-terek

Comment: Exactly. Also think about how books on curves and surfaces talk about the "first fundamental form" of a surface and just compute the coefficients $E$, $F$, and $G$. These are none other than the metric components $g_{ij}$. "First fundamental form" is the just name we use for "induced Riemannian metric" when teaching the subject to children....

Comment: Right that seems plausible, thank you. Could you still elaborate on how did you compute the pushforward $\iota_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\bigg|_{X(\theta,\varphi)}\right) = \frac{\partial X}{\partial\theta}(\theta,\varphi)$? @ivo-terek

Comment: Right. One possible definition of $\partial/\partial x^i|_p$, for $p$ in the domain of $\varphi = (x^1,\ldots, x^n): U\subseteq M \to \Bbb R^n$, is $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(p) = {\rm d}(\varphi^{-1})_{\varphi(p)} (e_i),$$where $e_i$ is the $i$-th vector in the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$. Here, $X = \varphi^{-1}$, the coordinates in $\Bbb R^2$ are called $\theta$ and $\varphi$, and so ${\rm d}X_{(\theta,\varphi)}(e_1) = (\partial X/\partial \theta)(\theta,\varphi)$.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is great, but here's a *pedestrian* version of the underlying nuts-and-bolts of the calculation since you asked "How do I find the metric given by this parametrization?" This is how I would find it.

---

With $\iota \circ X = (x, y, z)$, i.e.
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &= \sin\varphi\cos\theta \\
y &= \sin\varphi\sin\theta \\
z &= \cos\varphi, 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
we can calculate differentials:
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{d}x 
&= \cos\varphi\cos\theta\,\mathrm{d}\varphi 
- \sin\varphi\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta \\
\mathrm{d}y 
&= \cos\varphi\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\varphi 
+ \sin\varphi\cos\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta \\
\mathrm{d}z 
&= -\sin\varphi\,\mathrm{d}\varphi. 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Hence,
$$
\mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2 + \mathrm{d}z^2 
= \cdots (\text{trig identities}) \cdots
= \sin^2 \varphi\,\mathrm{d}\theta + \mathrm{d}\varphi^2, 
$$
which is the pullback of the euclidean metric $(\iota \circ X)^* g_E$ that you asked about, i.e. the symmetric rank $2$ tensor
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin^2 \varphi & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, this is also helpful. Should it be obvious that this $\mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2 + \mathrm{d}z^2$ is the pullback $(\iota \circ X)^* g_E$? @sammy-black

Comment: The euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with coordinates $(x, y, z)$ that we're pulling back is $\mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2 + \mathrm{d}z^2$, which is ultimately just the Pythagorean theorem in $3$ dimensions.

Comment: @Tim it is: see eq. 11.17 in Lee's book, page 286. Citing, "Using either of these formulas, the computation of pullbacks in coordinates is exceedingly simple".